# UICollectionView accumulating animations over different batch updates

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a problem with the animations of the `UICollectionView` over different batch updates. I'm using this code:

```
[collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
    if (touched) {
        [collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:markedItems];
        [collectionView insertSections:newSec];
    } else {
        [collectionView deleteSections:newSec];
        [collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:markedItems];
    }
} completion:nil];
```

Here's a [video of what I'm trying to do and the problem](http://db.tt/vBXOi2re). The idea is that when you touch on an image it'll animate it to the top, as the new main image and fade the other images. The problem is, when you go back and touch other image it'll animate this new touched image **and** the previous image.

I believe it's a `UICollectionView` bug and I can't figure out any workaround.

Here's a [sample project](http://db.tt/kOZpYxa1), if you want.

Comment: Seeing what appears to be the same thing here :/

Comment: @midas06 Very annoying… Probably is an UICollectionView bug. I'll wait another day and than I'll write a report at [the black hole](https://bugreport.apple.com/).

Comment: +1 for video and sample project

Comment: I'm about to make a DTS Request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Apple. Their engineers said that it's really a bug in UIKit and there's no know work around and that I should wait for the next major iOS preview releases (iOS 7) to check if that fixes the problem.